# Firebase authWithOPopup("facebook") won't redirect, left on white screen

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

I am creating an app that requires Facebook login and I am using the authWithOPopup in the Firebase API to do so. I have spent hours trying to fix this issue and there are many fixes already out there, but none of them have worked for me. I am testing the app with Ionic View.

When I serve the app in a browser it works perfectly, but it won't run inside the native environment. It works great on my Samsung Galaxy 5, but it will not work on any iPhoen that I have tried. The Facebook login appears then once the credentials are entered the screen turns white. Here is my code:

```
.controller('FacebookCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

$scope.login = function() {
    // Facebook login
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else { // Login successful
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:",
            ...
```

I have installed the appropriate InAppBrowser and cordova.js files:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I have attempted every step by step tutorial that I can find and it still will not work, The firebase version is 2.4.1 and the cordova version is 6.0.0.

Comment: Ionic View does not support the in-app-browser, which the facebook-auth requires. Have you tried installing the app on a device or an emulator? it should work there.

Comment: No I have not, I can't emulate IOS because I am using Linux. What do you recommend is the best way of emulating for either android or ios?

Comment: What version of the InAppBrowser are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest versions of everything

Answer (score 2):

This integration can be a tricky thing, because we (Firebase) do not have a programmatic way to detect the InAppBrowser, but rather try to sniff it out and make a best-effort attempt to use it. In cases where you're stuck at the white screen, that means that either (a) the entire page redirected, and the InAppBrowser is not actually being used or (b) the transport with Firebase is broken.

A few notes on debugging below, but *note* that you should check your InAppBrowser version. According to https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/193 the InAppBrowser was a bit broken for our use case between v1.2.0 until v1.3.0.

***Debugging:***

- On the page where you invoke `ref.authWithOAuthPopup(...)`, try `console.log(cordova)`. Is `cordova` in scope, or undefined? If undefined, look into your build process, or your script includes.
- Next, on the same page, try `window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');`. Is the app loading in the *InAppBrowser*, where you can see the popup frame with an option to close, or is the entire page being redirected? If the latter, dig into why the *InAppBrowser* is not available, starting with the existence of the `cordova` var in the page.
- If you've verified that the *InAppBrowser* is working properly, now validate that your OAuth application is properly configured by testing OAuth authentication with the provider of your choice on the web.